# In Google Apps Scripts, is there a way to create new tabs based on form data, then copy data into that newly created tab from multiple sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm setting up a Google Sheet that is connected to a Form. The Form is bringing in data from unique users. When a new user completes the form, and the data is stored in the Form Responses 1 tab, I want a new tab to be created that is named with the name of the new user. Additionally, I want to copy in some data to this newly created tab from two other, separate tabs... one row from the Form Responses 1 tab, and a large range of data and formulas from another tab (right now I have that tab named "Sheet 5").

I'm able to create a new tab and name it based on the unique user that shows up in the Form Responses 1 tab. However, I don't know how to copy the data from those other tabs into the newly created tab because I'm trying to use getSheetbyName, which requires me to provide a named sheet. Well, I don't have a named sheet because the target sheet to be copied into will always be based on new data that comes into the form.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
function onFormSubmit(){
  Logger.log('submit ran');

  var form = FormApp.openById('1oaGxmsd8SEDJ9HrXixpriCeKYrRxr1ZVX0x1zbohTIQ');
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onFormSubmit')
      .forForm(form)
      .onFormSubmit()
      .create();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');

  //Get last row of data
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var colB_Data = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 2).getValue();

  //var thisUser = 'theUserName';
  ss.insertSheet(colB_Data);

};

    function copyTo() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet5");
    var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("John Doe");

    var source = copySheet.getRange(1,1,4,2);
    var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,4,2);

    source.copyTo(destination);
```

The onFormSubmit function works, but the rest of the code is not working. I can't get data copied into a sheet that doesn't exist yet. It seems like I'd need the "John Doe" to be a variable that copies into each new sheet that is created

Comment: Why have you [made a second `copyTo()` function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet), and why do you expect it to run at the same time as `onFormSubmit` when it is not contained within that function? If you don't know the name of the sheet, why would you use `getSheetByName()` instead of [`getSheets()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets)? Do you intend to get [a single value from colB_Data](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue)? Spend time with docs

Comment: Can I ask you about the tags of Python?

Comment: `copyTo()` needs an argument e.g. `copyTo(sheetName)` so you can replace John Doe with a variable.  And as sinaraheneba said, you need to call `copyTo` inside of `onFormSubmit`.  But mostly I'm puzzled why you are setting up a trigger on each submission.  You do not need to do that.  Once the trigger is set, it continues to run.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onFormSubmit(e){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet5');
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,1,4,2);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var username=e.values[1];
  var nsh=ss.insertSheet(username);
  nsh.getRange(1,1,vA.length,vA[0].length).setValues(vA);
}
```

This code is written using the Spreadsheet Script Editor. And you have to create a onformSubmit trigger in the same project for the Spreadsheet.

[onFormSubmit Trigger for Spreadsheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

Comment: Thanks Cooper. I'm getting a TypeError: Cannot read property "values" from undefined in line 6. I'm guessing because the username values need to come from the Form Responses 1 sheet. How might I get those username values from that other sheet?

Comment: I hope you realize that you can't run the function from the script editor as it requires the event object.